# Replacing stdout with stderr

Tags: shell, io-redirection, file-descriptors

Is it possible to redirect the output from a command to replace the text sent to stdout with the text from stderr?

```
$ ./script
this line is redirected to stdout
this line is redirected to stderr

$ ./script (insert redirections here)
this line is redirected to stderr
```

I know I could just use `1>/dev/null`, but I want to know if there's a way to do this with the text from stderr redirected to stdout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
./script 2>&1 1>/dev/null
```

This redirects fd 2 to what fd 1 points to (i.e. `stdout`), then redirects fd 1 to `/dev/null`. The second redirect doesn't affect the first one, output to fd 2 will be sent to `stdout`.

Order does matter though. With this:

```
./script 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

will send all output to `/dev/null`.